# uninit_member: Non-static class member field m_cJobState.bstatus is not initialized in this constructor nor in any functions that it calls

Tags: c++, c++11

**I am getting the below warning at SubManager constructor:**

> Uninitialized scalar field (UNINIT_CTOR)
>
> uninit_member: Non-static class member field m_cJobState.bEULA is not initialized in this constructor nor in any functions that it calls.
>
> uninit_member: Non-static class member field m_cJobState.bstatus is not initialized in this constructor nor in any functions that it calls.
>
> uninit_member: Non-static class member field m_cJobState.eActivationState is not initialized in this constructor nor in any functions that it calls.

**Below is the code snippet:**

**SubManager.h file**

```
struct MgrStatus
{
    bool bEULA;                 
    bool bstatus; 
    WorkState eActivationState;
};

class SubManager
{
private:
    MgrStatus m_cJobState;   
};
```

**SubManager.cpp file**

```
SubManager::SubManager()
{
}
```

To resolve the warning,

Do we need to initialize structure variables in the above constructor?
If we need to initialize, how to initialize the enum variable (WorkState eActivationState;)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify from what tool you got warnings and also posted code
should give different errors I suspect. Seems that the tool requires you to initialize all aggregate members in constructors (C++ standard does not).

Since C++11 (question was tagged like that) it should compile and run with uniform initialization of aggregate members:

```
enum WorkState {SomethingElse, Crappy, Etc}; // wasn't defined in OP

struct MgrStatus
{
    bool bEULA;                 
    bool bstatus; 
    WorkState eActivationState;
};

class SubManager
{
public:
    SubManager();  // constructor declaration was missing in OP 
private:
    MgrStatus m_cJobState;
};

SubManager::SubManager()
    : m_cJobState{false,false,Crappy}
{ }

int main() // to demo it runs 
{ 
    SubManager s;
    (void)s; // just to silence unused variable s warning
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used coverity tool and it is showing this warning.